# Bash scripting - trying to set a variable to a string with a wildcard but its evaluating

Tags: bash

This is my problem:
`${4}` would be something like `someFile*.csv`

```
one_srcFile=${4}
```

If I run the script that contains the above from a directory that has a file that matches ie `someFile_incorrectfile.csv` then

```
${one_srcFile} = "someFile_incorrectfile.csv"
```

Where I am expecting

```
${one_srcFile} = "someFile*.csv"
```

Comment: It comes in as a param.

Comment: Positional parameter, then yes, `"$1-9"` are fine (0 is the scriptname). I thought you were trying to name a variable `4` You can run your script with `-f` (`noglob`) or `set noglob` to turn off pathname expansion. See `man bash` about line `4018`

Comment: `~/bin/myscript one two three 'someFile*.csv' five etc` — please note that the 4th argument is quoted

Comment: Thanks David. That fixed my issue. But seemed to cause issues further down the line but think I can resolve those.

Comment: Second issue resolved by setting globbing back on with set +f. Thanks David.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the wildcard `glob` is evaluating before it gets to your script, `Bash` will expand that before passing it as `$1`.